# PDF file download using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, download, fpdf

When I click a download button, an ajax request is send and the `HtmlToPDF()` php function is called.

First I will create a pdf file from an html file using FPDF. After that I want to download the pdf file created .

Code:

```
function HtmlToPDF()
    {       
        $fileName = $_POST['fileName']; 
        $file = basename($fileName, ".html");
        $pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $fp = fopen("../".$fileName,"r");
        $strContent = fread($fp, filesize("../".$fileName));
        fclose($fp);
        $pdf->WriteHTML($strContent);
        $fullPath = "../Bills/".$file.".pdf";       
        $pdf->Output($fullPath);

        if (is_readable ($fullPath)) {
            $fsize = filesize($fullPath);
            $path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);


            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header("Content-type: application/pdf"); // add here more headers for diff.     extensions
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\""); 
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');   // use 'attachment' to force a download              
            header('Expires: 0');
            header("Content-length: $fsize");
            header('Pragma: public');
            header ("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            echo file_get_contents($fullPath);          
            exit;       
        }   
    }
```

The PDF is created. but I can't download the file. the response is like

> %PDF-1.3
>   3 0 obj
>   <>
>   endobj
>   4 0 obj
>   <>
>   stream
>   x��YMS�0��W���h�aɽA��)�o�L,Rw�ۡÿ�l��a��!3�$��}z��}R9�P����Dd�D��D��(��_)YL~�&�$�c�3�zk{,�}�4pI4倒D   �D>���B��   ���m-?4۹
>   ��|�]7Ym�#`H���Tc�8��ӹ!�9�C�L�}?O�O�
>   �   � �
>   ��H�,���i�|��G�Q�S���?#R
>   GYB�KR�1�Qҡq��)��Ql�m�% {�/�_�c��XOۆQ`�����)<�Pg}Q��e�Χ7W��ɠ�����0e韉�e�.Βb��N�W �6�]
>   4�%�pJ�Wg��⡞ƕ�yw    �o�'��z�9��V� R��K#��>���<*f�*�r�6�
>   �
>   r|:�OEbfn�ia�]S��! C<܅���"���J�� Y}���1R������+2`��b�e��0Z�4H������i����g\h�    %R��p�0��c����ڵ�`�@ulW϶���Q�VJz��Vȋ5��J�!����4:��p��@|0�!��B�՚{ñ����X?[F([�pl��G�nHn�4��Q�o 2�����2�!�sަc-�?v��
>   S[�f&N�l�
>   &A���}^?P�8���x��X��$���i��ͳry��|gUZ�����X0=�Q^�W�Gʮ�G^'�8���Ԁ���ǯy���d��Ӵ�~�#�$h]3*������*��G�e�
>   endstream
>   endobj
>   1 0 obj
>   <
>   endobj
>   5 0 obj
>   <
>   endobj
>   6 0 obj
>   <
>   endobj
>   7 0 obj
>   <
>   endobj
>   2 0 obj
>   <
>   >
>   endobj
>   8 0 obj
>   <<
>   /Producer (FPDF 1.52)
>   /Creator (HTML2FPDF >> http://html2fpdf.sf.net)
>   /CreationDate (D:20130903060123)
>   >
>   endobj
>   9 0 obj
>   <<
>   /Type /Catalog
>   /Pages 1 0 R
>   /OpenAction [3 0 R /FitH null]
>   /PageLayout /OneColumn
>   >
>   endobj
>   xref
>   0 10
>   0000000000 65535 f 
>   0000000916 00000 n 
>   0000001304 00000 n 
>   0000000009 00000 n 
>   0000000087 00000 n 
>   0000001003 00000 n 
>   0000001099 00000 n 
>   0000001200 00000 n 
>   0000001412 00000 n 
>   0000001536 00000 n 
>   trailer
>   <<
>   /Size 10
>   /Root 9 0 R
>   /Info 8 0 R
>   >
>   startxref
>   1639
>   %%EOF

I saw some stack overflow question related to this. [PDF format error with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962001/pdf-format-error-with-php)

But can't solve my problem. Please help me..

Comment: How are you fetching the file?

Comment: ajax is NOT the answer to all questions

Comment: @Pekka Can u please explain ??

Comment: When you want to make a browser download something, you simply send it to the location, or create a hidden `<iframe>` pointing to the resource. No need for Ajax for the download part. See this question: [Javascript/jquery to download file via POST with JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3499597)

Answer (score 1):

According to FPDF documentation, you could use the second `Output()` argument

> Destination where to send the document. It can take one of the
>   following values:
>
> I: send the file inline to the browser. The plug-in is used if
>   available. The name given by name is used when one selects the "Save
>   as" option on the link generating the PDF.
>
> D: send to the browser and force a file download with the name given
>   by name.
>
> F: save to a local file with the name given by name (may include a
>   path).
>
> S: return the document as a string. name is ignored.

By using the `D` argument, it should force a download, without using AJAX

[Source](http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en)